Print long double value and clock_t as a double - ESP8266-RTOS-SDK
I can't print clock_t as a double or print time elapsed
void app_main()
{
 clock_t start, end;
 long double cpu_time_used;
 start = clock();
 
 ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Elapsed time");
 ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting time: %Lf", (long double)start);
 end = clock();
 ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Ending time: %ld", end);
 cpu_time_used = (( long double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Elapsed time: %Lf ms", cpu_time_used);
}

and this is my log:
I (241) application using mex: Elapsed time
I (243) application using mex: Starting time:
I (248) application using mex: Ending time: 2
I (255) application using mex: Elapsed time:  ms
I (264) application using mex: Elapsed time:  s
I really don't understand why

Try printing a double.  I suspect your ESP_LOGI() does not support long double.
IAC double is sufficient precision and range.
Use ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting time: %f", (double)start); or for exact value try ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting time: %a", (double)start);.
